# IQueryable to get sum and order by descending in subset

Tags: linq, fluent-nhibernate, iqueryable

I have a collection of DTO's in which I want to do some ordering by the sum of some values in a nested DTO.

The hiearchy is as follows:

Its a collction of QuestionDTO's.

A QuestionDTO has Many Answers which has Many Votes.

So in short:

1 QuestionDto: QuestionID, QuestionTitle, ANSWERS: AnswerId, Answer, VOTES: VoteId, AnswerId, Value

Its the last value that I want to have summed for each answer, and then order by this sum for each question. Making the most popular question/answer on top of the list.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
    var questionList = new List<Question>();//Get a real list

    var sortedQuestions = (from i in questionList
                           select new
                                   {
                                       i.QuestionID,
                                       i.QuestionText,
                                       VotesSum = i.Answers.Sum(ee => ee.Votes.Sum(ss => ss.Value))
                                   }
                           ).OrderByDescending(ee => ee.VotesSum);

    foreach (var item in sortedQuestions)
                Console.WriteLine(item.QuestionText + " " + item.VotesSum);
```

Asumming your classes are like these

```
class Vote
{
    public int VoteID { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

}
class Answer
{
    public int AnswerID { get; set; }
    public string AnswerText { get; set; }
    public List<Vote> Votes = new List<Vote>();
}

class Question
{
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers = new List<Answer>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to get what you want:

```
var query = questions.Select(q => 
        new { q.QuestionText,
              Answers = q.Answers.Select(a => 
                    new { a.AnswerText, 
                          Votes = a.Votes.Sum(v => v.Value)
                        })
            })
        .Select(q => 
            new { q.QuestionText, 
                  Votes = q.Answers.Sum(a => a.Votes), 
                  Answers = q.Answers.OrderByDescending(a => a.Votes)
                })
        .OrderByDescending(q => q.Votes);
```

As you see, the votes are summed at two levels, `Answer` and `Question` and sorted in descending order.